# Does Nlog variables store the same value until the session end

Tags: nlog

I am passing exception message via variable

```
 LogManager.Configuration.Variables["Exception"] = exception.ToString();
```

nlog.config

```
 <variable name="Exception" />
 <column name="EXCEPTION MESSAGE" layout="${var: Exception}" />
```

In log file, I created a custom nlog class where I am passing few values through variable as I mentioned above. If first time I got an exception then it is writing on log file again and again every next lines although there is no exception in next lines in same session until we get 2nd exception. And then 2nd exception is rewriting in all next lines.

How can I solve this? Is there any way that I can kill the previous variable value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store exceptions (or other context-information) in the NLog-Config-Variables.

Instead you should do this:

```
logger.Error(exception, "Something bad happened");
```

And modify your config to this:

```
<column name="EXCEPTION MESSAGE" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
<column name="EXCEPTION TYPE" layout="${exception:format=type}" />
<column name="EXCEPTION TARGETSITE" layout="${exception:format=Method}" />
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context and https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-layout-renderer

Comment: Thanks. that worked. but I need to show few more exception type like exception.GetType().ToString() ,  exception.Source,exception.TargetSite.ToString(), 
  exception.InnerException.Message,   exception.InnerException.Source, 
  exception.InnerException.TargetSite.ToString()   Can we pass this info too?

Comment: @Mhd Sounds like a different question. But have updated my answer with some more examples. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-layout-renderer

Comment: Thank you so much. that's exactly I wanted and link was very helpful.